# heroku local doesn't work fatal error: newosproc

Tags: python, heroku

I have a Flask app with just the basic files.

server.py:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello world'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn server:app --log-file=-
```

requirements.txt

```
Flask==0.10.1
Jinja2==2.8
MarkupSafe==0.23
Werkzeug==0.10.4
argparse==1.2.1
gunicorn==19.3.0
itsdangerous==0.24
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

I have installed heroku. The following commands run fine:

```
heroku login
heroku create
source venv/bin/activate
pip3 install Flask gunicorn
```

When I run `heroku local` it gives the following error:

```
runtime: failed to create new OS thread (have 6 already; errno=11)
fatal error: newosproc
```

Sometimes the `fatal error: newosproc` part doesn't appear.

I have even tried reinstalling Heroku and the Heroku-toolbelt but it has made no difference.

`python server.py` works just fine!

PS: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: While this issue exists when I run `heroku local` the app runs just fine on Heroku itself!

Comment: Same situation with perl and Mojolicious apps which tell me:  `heroku local` doesn't run saying `'local' is not a heroku command`. The apps run fine on Heroku's servers though.

Comment: `heroku version    
heroku-gem/3.9.1 (amd64-freebsd10) ruby/2.1.7`